# Hotkey to come back to where you were before F3?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

When you press <kbd>F3</kbd> or you hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on something in Eclipse it takes you to where the thing your cursor is on was declared.

Is there a hotkey to come back to where you were before? Also, is there a way to keep a history of some sort to press it twice to go back twice? This would be useful when going on "wild goose chases" looking for something random in large code bases.

The only similar thing I know is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to return to the last edit you made. Before going off you can change something arbitrarily and change it back, go hunting, and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to get back to the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> (back in history)

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> (forward in history)

Comment: Note that there are toolbar buttons for those (and **Last Edit Location** Ctrl+Q) - their icons are yellow left and right arrows.